# How to make A particular Web Page Grey on certain events like when the page is offline?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, progressive-web-apps

Here is a an offline version of https://www.flipkart.com/ on mobile which uses progressive web applications and greys out Content when User Is offline.
[image]

And Here is an Online version without greying
[image]

So How Do they Do It?

Comment: you can create an overlay with a grey / gray color and you're good (all with css with a javascript activation)

Comment: @mnemosdev will the color of the items in the respective page also adjust ?

Comment: yes, you would put a layer of color "in front" of them with the z-index css property, so all would be colored with the color you specified, like this, but without the menu: https://codepen.io/mnemosdev/full/bWvygd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others mentioned, you could use an overlay placed using `position: fixed` above the entire HTML. However this would not allow the user to click any elements beneath the overlay, so it depends on what you are after.

In the case of Flipkart, they apply the following CSS to the `<html>` tag:

```
filter: grayscale(1);
```

They also apply inline style to the individual elements, such as buttons to modify their colours. This approach will still allow you to navigate the site, which will come in handy if you allow for offline functionality.

Finally you will then need to add event listeners in JavaScript to handle when the user goes online or offline, such as below.

```
window.addEventListener('online', function(e) {
    // add your logic to update the UI when online
    console.log("You are online");
    document.body.style.filter = 'grayscale(0)';
}, false);

window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) {
    // add your logic to update the UI when offline
    console.log("You are offline");
    document.body.style.filter = 'grayscale(1)';
}, false);
```

Comment: Because the online/offline events only trigger when there is no network connection you won't catch all those lie-fi scenarios. For those you will want to add some 'fancy' logic to your fetch event logic where you hit the network. Add a catch handler to the promise change and postMessage to the client. There you can add the class or inline style to grey scale the UI.